# Flutter: List<Map<String, dynamic>> doesn't update ui

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I do function about increasing number of product. First I separate each product followed by its category using `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` that includes **name** and **amount**. When I click **+** button, it can print the increased number correctly in console. But in ui the number of product doesn't change immediately. It needs to click `ExpansionTile` to collapse and click it again to expand, then the number will increase.

This is my code for creating `ExpansionTile`.

```
ListView.builder(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   itemCount: categories.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
         color: CollectionsColors.purple,
      ),
      child: ExpansionTile(
         title: Text(
            categories[index],
            style: FontCollection.bodyBoldTextStyle,
         ),
         children: [
            Container(
               color: CollectionsColors.white,
               child: listData(categories[index]),
            ),
         ],
       ),
    );
  },
)
```

This is code for creating list of product in ExpansionTile.

```
Widget listData(String category) {
    ProductNotifier productNotifier = Provider.of<ProductNotifier>(context);
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> products = [];

    productNotifier.productList.forEach((product) {
      if (product.category == category) {
        products.add({'name': product.name, 'amount': 0});
      }
    });
    print(products);

    return ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  products[index]['name'],
                  style: FontCollection.bodyBlackTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  child: CustomStepper(
                      value: products[index]['amount'],
                      iconSize: 25,
                      increaseAmount: () {
                        products[index].update('amount', (value) => ++value);
                        print(products);
                      }
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

When I click `+` button in morning glory, it print in console correctly.

```
[{name: Morning Glory, amount: 1}, {name: Collard greens, amount: 0}, {name:  Cucumber, amount: 0}, {name: Carrot, amount: 0}]
```

But in ui doesn't change the value to 1. I need to click `ExpansionTile` to collapse and click it again to expand, then the number will change.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClassName extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/s-test";

  const ClassName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ClassNameState createState() => _ClassNameState();
}

class _ClassNameState extends State<ClassName> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> products = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      setState(() {
        ProductNotifier productNotifier = Provider.of<ProductNotifier>(context, listen:false);
        productNotifier.productList.forEach((product) {
          if (product.category == category) {
            products.add({'name': product.name, 'amount': 0});
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: CollectionsColors.purple,
            ),
            child: ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(
                categories[index],
                style: FontCollection.bodyBoldTextStyle,
              ),
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: CollectionsColors.white,
                  child: listData(categories[index]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget listData(String category) {
    return ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  products[index]['name'],
                  style: FontCollection.bodyBlackTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  child: CustomStepper(
                      value: products[index]['amount'],
                      iconSize: 25,
                      increaseAmount: () {
                        setState(() {
                          products[index].update('amount', (value) => ++value);
                          print(products);
                        });
                      })),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I try to use `setState()` but when I clicked increase button on each product, it printed only 1 but didn't increase like `amount += 1`.

Comment: This is print result in console when I clicked morning Glory

`[{name: Morning Glory, amount: 1}, {name: Collard greens, amount: 0}, {name:  Cucumber, amount: 0}, {name: Carrot, amount: 0}]`

Comment: and when I click next product 

`[{name: Morning Glory, amount: 0}, {name: Collard greens, amount: 1}, {name:  Cucumber, amount: 0}, {name: Carrot, amount: 0}]`

Comment: above sample answer works for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't work